# Extracting stdout return value in node js

Tags: node.js

I got a bash script, which output a integer value and how do I grab that value as a variable.

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var ftpsize;
exec('~/docker-project/ftp.check.sh',
  function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    if (error !== null) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
    ftpsize=stdout;
    console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
    console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
    }
});

console.log('stdout: ' + ftpsize);
```

stdout: 889951
and ftpsize as undifined, how do I extract the stdout as variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the callback that run after `ftp.check.sh` execute is called asynchronously, `ftpsize` will be undefined because the order of execution is:

1. start `exec`
2. `console.log('stdout: ' + ftpsize);` -> undefined
3. `exec` complete, `ftpsize=stdout;`

What you may want to look at is the concept of a "promise" in javascript. But, long story short, you want to define a function that return a "future value", and then you want to "await" for it to complete.

```
async function run() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    exec('~/docker-project/ftp.check.sh', function (error, stdout, stderr) {
      if (error !== null) {
        console.log(error);
        reject(error)
        return
      }

      console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
      console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
      resolve(stdout)
    })
  })
}
```

which you can then consume with `const ftpsize = await run()` or `run().then(ftpsize => { /* ... */ })`

Comment: thanks for the reply, however when I'm using as follows, 
app.get("/ftp", (req, res, next) => {
        const test = await run()
        res.json({'status': 'on', 'used': test });
})
But I'm getting SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules

Comment: Use the `then` variant, or add an `async` to the route

Comment: Sorry mate, I don't think I got it. I want to do the restful call with the data I get from the bash.